# List Active Sessions in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I have a Flask Server, and I'm using the session object in requests. However, I also have a background thread that runs occasionally for cleanup, which does not run within any handler.

How would I generate a list of active session objects across all clients? So for example, if Client A has Session A, Client B has Session B, Client C has Session C, I would like to access a list along the lines of [Session A, Session B, Session C].

It appears there's no mention of this in the Flask or Flask-Session documentation, but it seems like this should be possible since we're obviously storing all session information somewhere.

Comment: Flask doesn't know anything about "clients".  It just has a collection of "sessions".  The backing store is determined by the `SESSION_TYPE` you configured.  I don't believe there is a generic way to enumerate them.

Comment: @TimRoberts So I'd have to modify the backing store to somehow be able to list active sessions if I wanted to do this?

Comment: Again, it depends on the SESSION_TYPE in your configuration.  Some of the session types store the session data in the cookie itself, so there IS no local copy of the data.  You'll have to troll the source code.  It isn't going to be easy.

Comment: @LangstonNashold did you find a solution? I also need a way to cleanup after old sessions.

Comment: @Steve it seemed like it was potentially possible using certain server side sessions, but needlessly difficult. So I ended up just using a different solution.